# footer and weird spacing and positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css

so my footer is acting really wierd. It was working before but now there is this wierd spacing and when you scroll up it follows the page and creates extra space. The idea was to have a sticky footer that would always stay at the bottom of the page via http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ . The code for the scss is here:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
header {
    padding: 1em;
    background:#EFDECD; //#5ee;
    text-align: center;

}

#content {
    padding: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
footer {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:5em;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#EFDECD; //#EFDECD
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    a{
        padding: .75rem;
       // position:relative;
        top: 1.5em;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
    p{
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
}

video{
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
//header{
////margin-top: 3ems;
//    background-color: lightgrey;
//}

//footer{
//    height: 5em;
//    background-color: lightgrey;
//    position: relative;
//   bottom: 0px;
//   width: 100%;
//
//}
.label{
margin-left: .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
}
table{
font-size: .75em;
}

.panel.callout a:not(.button):hover{
  color: $anchor-font-color-hover;
}
.headtext{
    display:inline-block;
 //   font-size:3em;
    margin: 0 5em;
    text-align: center;
 //   font-family:"Courier New";
  //  font-weight: bold;
 //   margin-left: 6em;

}
.img2{
   // max-height: 20%;
    max-width: 25%;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
   }

.accorborder{
border: black dotted 1px;
}
h6{font-weight: bold;}
```

and the actual link for the site is located at www.new.omegadesignla.com
so please feel free to check it out and inspect it from the source. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this snippet:

```
footer {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:5em;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#EFDECD; //#EFDECD
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    a{
        padding: .75rem;
       // position:relative;
        top: 1.5em;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
    p{
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
}
```

to this one:

```
footer {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:5em;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#EFDECD; //#EFDECD
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    a{
        padding: .75rem;
       // position:relative;
        top: 1.5em;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
    p{
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
}
```

note I just changed the position:absolute; to position:fixed;

Comment: thanks this definitely works. I tried changing from relative to absolute and vica versa but i completely forgot about fixed, lol. Thanks!

Comment: thanks what would i need to change if i just wanted the regular footer not the sticky one?

Comment: you can try position:static;for the regular one.

Comment: thanks, the only thing is in full screen i would like it to show the footer at the bottom but right now there is a lot of white space between the footer and it scrolls. I would like to try to make it so it does not scroll and brings the footer up on full screen. If you know what im trying to say?

Comment: With the position:fixed; the footer won't scroll. It has a fixed position within the document. If you want to change the behavior of your footer depending on the window size you can use media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Did you add any styling libraries after this was instated right click and inspect element do the styles match what you've put down. If it was working it might be conflicting css.

I've just jumped on Your page and had a look it looks like there is a percentage attribute effecting the layout if it was me I'd arrange the footer to clearfix after the main body

Ps nice mobile site

Comment: Hello sorry about the slow reply you need to make the child clear the parent element with this it is dependant on the code have a look at this.http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/